# XSLT namespace in source file referencing in XPath

Tags: xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

i have spent hours with my problem until i realized that the XPath in the XSL file does not match my source document as long as there is a namespace defined in the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../../../clonk.xsl"?>
<clonkDoc xmlns="https://clonkspot.org"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="https://clonkspot.org ../../../clonk.xsd">
    <func>
        <some-more-elements/>
    </func>
    <author>Author</author><date>lazy date</date>
</clonkDoc>
```

The `xmlns="https://clonkspot.org"` is needed as far as I know that the document can be referenced with an XSD.

My XSL file looks as following ("head" and "nav" not shown here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:clonk="https://clonkspot.org">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
                doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"/>
    <xsl:template match="/clonk:clonkDoc/clonk:func">
        <html>
            <xsl:call-template name="head"/>
            <body>
                <xsl:call-template name="nav"/>
                <h1>
                </h1>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

The result looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

    <html xmlns:clonk="https://clonkspot.org">
    <head>...
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1></h1>
    </body>
</html>
    Authorlazy date
```

I've two problems with it:

1. I have no "clonk:" elements in the target html document but in the `<html>`-element the namespace is defined.
2. I would like to save the "clonk:" in all XPath in the XSL.

How do I tell the XSLT processor to interpret `<template match="/clonkDoc/func">` to the default namespace of the source XML document (where `xmlns="https://clonkspot.org"`)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude the `xmlns:clonk="https://clonkspot.org"` declaration from the output, add this to the `xsl:stylesheet` start-tag.

```
exclude-result-prefixes="clonk"
```

I did not understand your 2nd question. If you are asking how to define a default namespace that will be used for any unprefixed element name included in any XPath expression in the stylesheet, then the answer is that you need XSLT 2.0 for that:
https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unprefixed-qnames

Comment: Used `xpath-default-namespace="https://clonkspot.org"` like you said and it worked. I saw it some days before but the XSLT processor of my PhpStorm wasn't able to interpret this. Also xsltproc supports version 1 only. Now using saxonb-xslt and the XPaths are interpreted correctly!